# Computer not booting from Grub or USB

Tags: windows-10, crash, ubuntu-16.04

I have a 3 years old Dell XPS 8700 (SSD 256, HD 3TO, 32G Ram, Intel I7) shipped with Windows 8 and subsequently upgraded with Windows 10. I have recently installed Ubutuntu 17.04 which seemed to work properly.

Today My computer froze and I tried to reboot it. Though Once in grub, whether I choose Windows or Ubuntu I get a blackscreen.

I tried to log from a USB stick with a version of Ubuntu 16.04. I selected "try Ubuntu" but then again black screen.

From the grub I tried "check disk errors" but failure again. Dell Bios diagnostics show no problem. (Though I suspect something is faulty somewhere or maybe SSD is dead or some corrupted data) Also I tried to Boot directly into Windows from the Bios and bypass Grub, which gave me Windows Recovery (though I have never made a recovery disk) and cannot go further here.

My concern at the moment would be to retrieve some files on SSD disk which holds the Windows partition. The best would be to boot Ubuntu from a USB disk and migrate important files to HD before attempting things on the SSD ? Otherwise should I just remove the SSD and recover through an USB3 adapter ?

And then maybe wipe it and try to reinstall Ubuntu (my Windows is OEM so no install disk at hand and I don't mind having Ubuntu only)

Comment: Did you recently install a BIOS patch or update, like in the last 2 weeks?

Comment: It goes in the back but I don't think I did. Bios shows a date in 2014. Also I managed to have Ubuntu splash (from stick)  but it is failing shortly after. Some list of errors flicker for a few milliseconds and mentions "Radeon", so maybe my card is dead. Then a square of color shows on the top right corner and nothing.

Comment: Can you boot into the BIOS? Check your settings there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine should boot from a USB flash or external HDD even if there were *no* SSD or HDD. If, as you state, "I tried to log from a USB stick with a version of Ubuntu 16.04. I selected "try Ubuntu" but then again black screen," then the issue is not with the SSD, but with hardware or the UEFI/BIOS boot setup, most likely the display setup.

- [Check that the clock/CMOS cell is good.](https://www.dell.com/community/Desktops-General/XPS-8700-0KWTv8-won-t-boot-CMOS-issue/m-p/5174301)
- Reseat connectors and cards, particularly the video card. These connectors may work loose over time. If the video card has a cooling fan, use canned air to clean it and to ensure it spins.
- [Update the BIOS](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln284433/what-is-bios-and-how-to-update-the-bios-on-your-dell-system?lang=en#How_to_update_USB_flash_drive), if you can, obtained [from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=WVHKG), to repair it.
- [Check BIOS setup.](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln129956/dell-bios-updates?lang=en) [The System Setup instructions are on p. 76 of the Dell 8700 manual.](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/xps-8700/manuals) In particular, check the Intel multi-display option

Comment: Actually, the XPS line comes with high-end Nvidia graphics for which it's often needed the additional boot parameter `nomodeset` until the Nvidia drivers are installed.

Comment: Yep on my Dell laptop I have a USB stick and some Linux distribution requires `nouveau.nomodest=0` but this desktop never complained when i installed Ubuntu 17.04. Though now I see Ubuntu start (on stick) and it fails with some error message flickering about "Nvidia" . Then I see a big colored squared on top right then nothing. Thanks Dr Moishe, I am going through the checks now.

Comment: @Michaelbay you are correct, nomodeset does boot into the stick. Great. I can see my drives. HD is fine. though when i click on the SSD (with Windows parititon only) it gives me this : **Error mounting /dev/sdb5 at /media/ubuntu/OS: Command-line 'mount t "stfs" -o "uhelper=udisk2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sdb5" "/media/ubuntu/OS" exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sdb5': Operation not permitted The NTFS parition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting),...**

Comment: @DrMoishe Cell seems good but I have replaced CR2032 as it was 4 years old. I removed graphic card and reinstated. Also removed msata hard drive and dusted. All back in place.  I have not yet performed the two last checks with the bios but once Ubuntu stick is loaded, I egt above comment error when trying to access SSD

Comment: @Maxence That's entirelly expected due to the Fast Startup feature of any Windows 8 or newer. (NTFS) drives are semi-hibernated just like the message says.

Comment: Thanks Michael, at the moment there is no way to get back to windows normally. safe mode (which i never really used in win 10 seems to be accessible from Windows only). Do you think trying this would work : https://askubuntu.com/questions/204166/how-do-i-mount-a-hibernated-ntfs-partition Also I understand windows is hybernated but why can't I access my Ubuntu session from grub (not from stick, a real partition on second drive)

Comment: OK PB FOUND. Thanks to both of you. I cleaned the graphic card as much as I could. But finally removed it completely and activated Intel Multi Display in the bios to be able to connect my HDMI scrren on my motherboard and TADA All gone. No more session lock ... DPU dead (now need to replace it in order to have dual display)

Comment: @Maxence, before discarding the old GPU, check if a  needed driver for it is missing or damaged.